# Page re-load on AJAX return looses focus on button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a button click action upon which I make AJAX call to update a field. After the AJAx returns, I am doing this -

```
     document.location.reload(true);
```

The page reloads, however, the focus is not returning to the button. Can you suggest a means where I can reload/refresh the page and the focus returns on the button to click again?

I have updated my AJAX code here, please tell me how to modify this -

```
<input type="button" name="IncreaseMyDate" id="myDate"  value="Increase" onclick="updateMyDate('<%=myDate%>')"/>


     function updateMyDate(mywDate)
{
    XMLHttpObj_myDate = CreateHttpObject();

    if(XMLHttpObj_myDate == null){
        alert("HTTP Request not supported");
        return;
    }

     var itemId = document.getElementById("itemId").value;   

    document.getElementById("myDate").setAttribute("disabled",true) ;
    var url ="IncreaseMyDate.jsp?action=update&myDate="+reviewDate; 

    document.getElementById("myDate").style.cursor = "not-allowed"; 
    XMLHttpObj_myDate.onreadystatechange=fillMyDate;
    XMLHttpObj_myDate.open("GET",url);
    XMLHttpObj_myDate.send(null);

    return false;

}



function fillMyDate(){
    if(XMLHttpObj_reviewDate.readyState == 4 || XMLHttpObj_myDate.readyState == "complete"){
        document.getElementById("myDate").style.cursor = "pointer"; 
        document.getElementById(myDate").innerHTML = XMLHttpObj_myDate.responseText; 

     document.location.reload(true);
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do the page reload? The big advantage of making Ajax calls is that they avoid the need to reload the page. You could just do all the Ajax work server-side when you are reloading the page.

You need to pass a variable to the new page load that indicates what button should have the focus. Your page reload doesn't know about what was happening client-side before. Pass the id of the button in the query string and then use it to find the button again and set the focus.

Answer (score 0):

You could store the button's id in `sessionStorage`, and then check when the page loads to reapply the focus if applicable.

The following page worked in my tests:

```
<body onload="body_onload();">
<button id="buttonA" onclick="button_click(this);">Button A</button><br/>
<button id="buttonB" onclick="button_click(this);">Button B</button><br/>
<button id="buttonC" onclick="button_click(this);">Button C</button><br/>
</body>

<script>
    function body_onload() {
        var buttonId = sessionStorage["buttonId"];
        if (buttonId) {
            document.getElementById(buttonId).focus();
        }
    }
    function button_click(button) {
        sessionStorage["buttonId"] = button.id;
        document.location.reload(true);
    }
</script>
```